# Git merge commits cause merge conflicts

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have two branches on a repo. One called master, and one called dev. Master is treated like production, and only gets occasional merges from branches created from dev. However, it happens that master gets commits that are not in dev every once in a while (hotfixes). Because of this, I merge master into dev periodically.

I have now run into a situation where merging master into dev causes a lot of conflicts. I have cherry-picked all of the actual changes that went into master into dev, so the code itself SHOULD be identical. However, when I go to merge master into dev, I get conflicts anyway. From what I can tell, these conflicts are coming from the actual merge commits that happened when I merged branches into master (they went into dev too). **Any idea what might be going on here, and how to fix this from happening in the future?**

```
              /--hotfix branch--\
master ------/-------------------\(merge commit)-----\---------------
                                 |                    |
dev ---------------------------(merge commit)-------(lots of conflicts!)
```

If it is hard to tell from the diagram, A hotfix is created off of master, changes are made, and then merged into master. I then take that hotfix and merge it into dev too. The physical code at this point should be the same. However, when I try to merge master into dev now, I see a bunch of conflicts, most of which stem from the code changed in the hotfix as if I had never merged the hotfix into dev (I double checked, I did merge it into dev).

Comment: Are you trying to cherry-pick the merge-commits you have on master? (I mean, in addition to obviously cherry-picking the non-merge-commits)

Comment: It's unclear to me because at different points in your post you're saying different things;  When you propagated the hotfix to dev, did you *merge* master into dev, or did you *cherry-pick* master commits into dev?  Are you currently *merging*, or are you *cherry-picking*?  These are very different things, and knowing which combination of actions we're talking about is important.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger when I propogated the hotfix, I merged it directly into dev, as well as to master. I.E. two separate MRs (in gitlab), which create two separate merge commits, one on dev, and another on master.

Comment: Ok.  So what were you talking about cherry picking?

Comment: after the merges, and seeing that there were merge conflicts, I cherry-picked the commits with changes (not merge commits), to make sure the code really was all up to date (it is).

Comment: Feels like you are doing "almost GitFlow". Why not just use GitFlow? Then you could use the CLI extensions to make sure all the branches are merged to each other appropriately.

Comment: The question here is more why do I get these merge conflicts, and what is the best practice for avoiding them in this case. GitFlow specifies the same behavior I am using currently. I'd like to know what I am doing wrong before using an extension that fixes it for me.